# How to create two postgres docker containers from docker compose file , one for development and one for testing?

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

So for example this is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  postgres:
    container_name: mydevdb
    image: postgres:13
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      - POSTGRES_DB=${POSTGRES_DB}
    volumes:
      - postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
volumes:
  postgres:
```

And I want to have an image for development and another for testing with different (container name, POSTGRES_USER, POSTGRES_PASSWORD, POSTGRES_DB and port)

I want the best approach for that. Thanks.

Comment: Create a second docker-compose file for the test environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to give the services different names. (and maybe different port exposures, depending on how you want to use them)

```yaml
version: "3.7"
services:
  postgres-dev:
    container_name: mydevdb
    image: postgres:13
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      - POSTGRES_DB=${POSTGRES_DB}
    volumes:
      - postgres-dev:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
  postgres-test:
    container_name: mytestdb
    image: postgres:13
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      - POSTGRES_DB=${POSTGRES_DB}
    volumes:
      - postgres-test:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
volumes:
  postgres-dev:
  postgres-test:
```